# Master thesis, master's degree thesis or master degree thesis

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

I searched online and I understood that "master's degree" retains the apostrophe, while the relative thesis is commonly referred to as "master thesis". However, of the forms

- Master thesis
- Master's degree thesis
- Master degree thesis

Which one is wrong, which is right and which should be preferable to use on a thesis cover? I know that in English theses it's common to use the phrase "Thesis prepared for the Degree of Master of Science" but I can't do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24377/use-master-thesis-or-masters-thesis

"Grammatically speaking, master's thesis unequivocally means a thesis of a master. Master thesis can be read the same way, but also as primary, principle or main thesis.

Stick with master's thesis."

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=master%27s+thesis&btnG=

Comment: Your second link gives 1,770,000 results, while for "master thesis" it gives 4,400,000 results (https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=master+thesis&btnG=).

Comment: Correct. If you click through the search results you'll see that "master's thesis" also appears. The term has been aggregated to the "master thesis" search results. The n-gram search shows that "master's thesis" is more prevalent. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=master+thesis%2Cmaster%27s+thesis&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmaster%20thesis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmaster%20%27s%20thesis%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Indeed! I thought I shall change my CV now, but I see that I used "MS" there :) And in one place "master's thesis" correctly. The good thing is that it can be both lowercase (which I used) and uppercase (which looks more frequent).